# Function domain and simplification: how to combine them?

Tags: functions

What is the domain of the real-valued function:

$$f(x) = \frac{x+4}{(x+4)(x-6)}$$

Wolfram|Alpha says [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2b4%29/%28%28x%2b4%29%28x-6%29%29):

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ne -4, x \ne 6 \} $$

I believe it should be more like this:

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ne 6 \} $$

I couldn't find any explanation of this on the Internet. Please, could you give some references on why the first answer should be considered as correct. Maybe I just do not understand what the function domain is?

**Update**

It seems that to understand explanations I should first see true mathematical rigorous definitions of *function*, *expression*, *domain*, etc on this topic. Could you include any of these in your answers, please?

Answer (score 1):

That's mostly a matter of definition. Literally, $$
  f(x) = \frac{x+4}{(x+4)(x-6)}
$$
is *not* defined for $x=-4$, because in general $\frac{0}{0}$ is *undefined*. You can, however, easily *extend* $f$ from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-4,6\}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{6\}$ while keeping properties like continuity and the like intact.

That extension is, in fact, so simple in the case of your $f$ that most people will automatically do it in their head, i.e. will cancel the troublesome $x+4$ terms, and thus actually work with $$
  f(x) = \frac{1}{x-6}
$$
which of course *is* defined for $x=-4$.

Still, literally speaking, Wolfram Alpha is correct to say that your $f$ is undefined for both $x=-4$ and $x=6$. Even though that undefined-ness is pretty artificial.

Here's an analogy which might help explain the two different viewpoints that lead to two different answers here. Say you're standing on a street with a friend, and are looking at a car. He says "That care looks exactly like mine". You answer "No, it doesn't. The license plates have different numbers on them". Who's correct? Literally speaking, you are - two cars with different license plates obviously don't look *exactly* the same. But the difference is trivial, and since the license plates will *obviously* be different since it's not actually his car, it's clear that he was referring to everything *else* being equal.

Comment: So, are there several correct answers?

Comment: Nitpicking: you should $1/(x-6)$ not call $f$.

Comment: And there is only one answer: the $f\colon\boldsymbol{R}\setminus

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Why not? If fgp views it as a rational function (the most reasonable way to view it), we have $$\frac{x+4}{(x+4)(x-6)} = \frac{1}{x-6}$$ by defintion of rational functions.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I don't think I did. What I wrote was that most people will *read* the definition as $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-6}$. That's not the same thing as me saying that they *are* equal - they're just often *treated* as equal. But it depends on the context of course...

Comment: And there is only one answer: the $f\colon\boldsymbol{R}\setminus\{-4,6\}$, defined by $f(x)=\frac{x+4}{(x-6)(x-4)}$ can be uniquely continuously continued to a function $\hat f\colon\boldsymbol{R}\setminus\{-4\}$ defined by $\hat f(x)=1/(x+6)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's compulsory for defining a function to tell what it's domain is.  So are the functions $f\colon \boldsymbol R\to \boldsymbol R$, $x\mapsto f(x):=x^2$ and $g\colon\boldsymbol{R}_+\to\boldsymbol R$, $x\mapsto g(x):=x^2$ different.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe But the point of the question is that the domain was not specified. So the question is how to interpret the symbols to decide which domain we want.

Comment: @DanielFischer So the question was ill-posed.  But anyway, $f\neq \hat f$ since $\hat f$ has one more point than $f$.  *Not* according to Emanuele it's mandatory to tell what the domain of a function is.  Always.  To avoid such fruitless discussions as this one.

Answer (score 0):

When not specified elsewhere, the domain of a function given as an expression, is the largest set in which the expression makes sense. If the expression contains a fraction, the denominator must be different from zero.

Comment: Yes. My set is larger. And function is defined on -4. What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: But the expression is not defined in $-4$ since the denominator becomes $0$ and the fraction $x/y$ is not defined when $y=0$.

Comment: So, we can only find domain for the expression but not for the function?

Comment: @AndreyYankin You are confusing between an “expression” and a “function”. First of all functions are rules, they map one number $x$ to another (which we denote by $f(x)$) according to that rule, $f$. We write $f:x\mapsto f(x)$. Some functions can be described by expressions, like yours $f:x\mapsto \tfrac{x+4}{(x+4)(x-6)}$. However, an expression doesn't have a domain. A domain is only a characteristic of a function, which we determine by collecting all the values for which the expression makes sense, i.e. for which the expression is defined, like when we have something of the form $x/0$... etc

Answer (score 0):

The ratio $\frac{0}{0}$ can be found only as a limit. For $x=-4$ you have the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0\dot{}(-10)}$ wich is unacceptable

Answer (score 0):

It stems from the difference between the functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-6}$ and $f(x)=\frac{x+4}{(x+4)(x-6)}$. Notice that the former is defined on all values of the real line except at $x=6$, but the latter is not defined on $x=6$ as well as $x=-4$. The graph of the second function will be almost the same as the graph of the first function, except for the fact that it contains a "hole" (undefined point) at $x=-4$.